# Why bother with airlock when I can just leave the tube going to the bleach water in place?

Tags: fermentation, airlock

Making my first batch!  Using a Brooklyn Brew Shop kit, and did the active part last night.  I've got the jug in a cool/dark place and it it bubbling away, sending CO2 through the tube in the top of the jug into pot of bleachy water.  My question:  why bother taking out the tube and installing the airlock, like the instructions say to do after a couple of days?  Why not just leave the tube in there, going out to the bleachy water?  Seems to serve fine, but then there might be something I haven't considered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: sure, that is fine and jsled is absolutely right.

Long answer: the other thing to consider is just don't bother with blowoff, which I assume is the reason for the bleach water setup, and just use an airlock.

I think being really concerned with blowoff is probably a side-effect of following old Charlie Papazian instructions or people who followed his lead. I know he said blowoff gets rid of a lot of unwanted gunk and fusel alcohols that affect taste of the finished product, but I'm not so sure that's true in a negative (or any?) way and I don't think large breweries tend to worry much about blow-off either. Plus it seems to me there is a slight risk of infection from using/changing blowoff tubes.

You need  blowoff if your vessel is too small, but nowadays I personally would use a bigger vessel.

Comment: Ah OK.  The kit that I was given uses a 1-gallon jug, which is almost full.  I guess that's why the instructions call for blowoff.  But then why would they bother calling for you to take out the tube and fit the airlock after a few days?

Comment: Other than that some people probably don't want a big gunky container of bleach awkwardly lying around, probably no real reason.

Comment: Oh, well,  you might also think of it as a minimum time to leave the blowoff tube set up.  :-D But I think it's up to you whether you let fermentation finish out with that sort of airlock.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can leave the blow-off tube in place if you like. It is just a big airlock, anyways.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the answer.  Why do people bother with airlocks if the blow-off tube accomplishes the same purpose?

Comment: Some of us don't. :)  As BBS point out, an airlock (or just foil over the mouth) is more self-contained and tidier.

Answer (score 2):

Using an airlock certainly makes handling the vessel easier as it's all self contained, but hopefully you won't have to handle the vessel much.

I liked using an airlock because it was a more compact and simple setup. However, after having a batch overflow the airlock and make a mess while I was out of town  my wife insists that I use a blow-off. I'm happy to do that as there is little functional difference between the two and using the blow-off tube eliminates the chance of making a mess again.